# How to build a confirmation message in a popup for a website built on .NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement a confirmation message appearing in a popup when a user clicks on a button on a web page built on .NET Core. Then the user can either accept or cancel that message, if they decline then I need them to stay on the same page.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.For, Model.Sources, new { @id = "ddl" })
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>
         <input type="file" name="csvFile" />
      </p>
      <p>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="DisplayConfirmation()">Upload File</button>
      </p>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayConfirmation() {

        var confirm_value = document.getElementById("ddl");
        if (confirm_value.value == " Data") {
            if (window.confirm("Do you want default package?")) {
                            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: when click on button it call the javascript function, after check the condition to display pop up, when it display pop up and click on cancel button it still hit the endpoint on server side. Can someone help that how do stop it to call endpoint when click on cancel button??+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had success using this approach taking the confirmation and putting it in a boolean variable first, skipping 'window':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayConfirmation() {
        var confirm_value = document.getElementById("ddl");
            if (confirm_value.value == " Data") {
                var confirmed = confirm("Do you want default package?");
                if (confirmed) {

                }
            }
        }
 </script>
```

If the confirm returns false, just let the function run out and nothing will happen.